# How true caller access the incoming call detail? Like incoming number and Name in iPhones?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Currently we are getting error during access incoming calling number information in iOS/Xcode. Please suggest answer using Objective C.

How we detect incoming calling number in our iOS app?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Comment: I hope you can't, since this will be a huge breach of privacy,

Comment: Ca you please give me brief description about True caller app working methodology about access the contact information.

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible.**

Unfortunately that is not possible. That kind of data and information is far too private to be accessible for everyone.

**Update:**

I have checked into true caller app in iOS, But there is not such functionality like fetching call log.

Thank you.

Comment: So how Actually true caller work for access the contact information

Comment: I have checked into true caller app in iOS, But there is not such functionality like fetching call log.

Comment: Im not tallking about call logs, Im just talking about incoming calling number information.

Comment: Both are same things, incoming calling number information also fall in call logs